Why is my IIS Website for a FastAPI application showing Invalid Hostname / Bad Request?
I'm trying to host a FastAPI application using IIS. I've been using this example to try and deploy a basic FastAPI application, but I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly. I've also used the Microsoft IIS for Python reference
(I am using Windows 11)
In order of what I've done so far:

Setup FastAPI application and tested it using

python -m uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8800

The application is located at C:\test-fastapi as per the instructions from the link above.
I can access this using the IP address of my local computer from elsewhere on my LAN.

For IIS now, using version 10 with HttpPlatformHandler installed.
I've created an Application Pool called test-fastapi, with No Managed Code and Integrated Managed Pipeline for the settings.
Added a site with host name as test, port 9000 and my local IP address, (https://i.sstatic.net/LhWsLjNd.png)
The name I've given is testfastapi and the application pool used is test-fastapi. Physical path is C:\test-fastapi

Added a web.config file in C:\test-fastapi with the following configurations:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="C:\Program Files\Python312\python.exe"
                  arguments="-m uvicorn --port %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% --host 0.0.0.0"
                  stdoutLogEnabled="true"
                  stdoutLogFile="C:\<PC-name>\LogFiles\python.log"
                  startupTimeLimit="60"
                  processesPerApplication="16">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="" value="" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>


Added IIS_IUSRS for Full Access in my Python directory and for the C:\test-fastapi directory

When I browse at http://test:9000 I get a DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN and if I do <IP_address>:9000, I get Bad Request - Invalid Hostname, HTTP Error 400
I'm open to other deployment methods, but am limited to using Windows/Server 2012
Edit 1:
So I've been trying other things. For one, I changed my Python installation from system-wide to user specific. I was and am still getting the error C:\Users\<PCName>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe: No module named uvicorn
pip list is showing uvicorn is installed and the only location that python is installed is the one above. I can run the fastapi server from my C:\test-fastapi folder fine from powershell, so I'm a bit stumped as to why I'm getting this error. I'm not using a virtual environment, but I think I'll try that next.


The "Bad Request" error is commonly caused by invalid IIS site binding, https://docs.lextudio.com/jexusmanager/tutorials/binding-diagnostics. You need to configure your DNS settings to resolve test to the right IP address to resolve it (or switch to another site binding). 2) To verify if the "no module" error makes sense, you should run C:\Users\<PCName>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe -m pip list (not any other pip list which might resolve things differently).


You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 404 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.
